# XML tag related questions

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("note.xml");

print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
?>
```

In the above code sample I don't understand the last line. why we use saveXML(). Is there anyway to print the xml file without using saveXML(). Please anyone can answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the xml from a file and you are not modifying it in any way, there's no need to call `saveXML()`. [saveXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) is mostly used when you create an xml document from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check the contents of the file, you could use `file_get_contents`, instead of using DomDocument. DomDocument is more useful when you want to make changes or parse.